# Inject Factories - How and why?

Tags: java, factory, factory-pattern

In a code review the following comments came up: "I think, you actually mean to inject the factory as an instance, so that you can rebind the factory if needed." and "important hint: Factories should not be static, but should be injected."

Test.java:

```
Foo foo = FooFactory.get(argument);
```

FooFactory.java:

```
public final class FooFactory {
    public static Foo get(String argument) {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

How should I have done it otherwise? What does "rebind" mean in the first comment of the reviewer?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the reviewer what she meant.

Comment: Have you asked the code reviewer to explain it to you in more detail? Personally, I have no clue what he is talking about.

Comment: What would "rebinding" buy you?  If your factory is not interface based, I see no reason to inject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By doing what you did, you basically ignored dependency injection, and used a static factory instead. So, if in a unit test, you want your factory to return fake instances of Foo rather than real instances, you can't.

Instead, you should use dependency injection (Spring example here):

```
public class SomeService
    private FooFactory fooFactory;

    @Autowired
    public SomeService(FooFactory fooFactory) {
        this.fooFactory = fooFactory;
    }

    public void someMethod(String arg) {
        Foo foo = fooFactory.create(arg);
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

And now, in a unit test, you can inject whatever FooFactory implementation you want (typically, a mock).

Comment: There were Unit Tests, so I assume this is what the reviewer meant. Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: I'm new to DI. It's certainly great to have the factory here but the factory will instantiate a Foo using new keyword, which leads to the foo object not managed by the DI container. Is it OK this way? I guess my question is that when should a class be managed by a container and when would it be ok to just use new keyword? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With most dependency injection frameworks you can bind a particular object implementation at run time. I would wager that is what the reviewer is referring too. To take advantage of this you would, of course, have to inject your factory as opposed to statically creating it.